# Connect two combox with each other and DB using html and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to connect two combox in html to DB with php and use the result from the combox to get something else from the DB

for exemple

```
<div style="margin:5px">סוג הפעילות
    <select name = "ex" id = "user" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
         <option value = "0">  </option>
     <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $row['NameEx'];?>"><?php echo $row['NameEx'];}?></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div  name = "sub" id="sub" style="margin:5px"> תת פעילות</div>
<div><button class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" name="submit1" onclick = "calc()" >חשב</button></div>
```

and my javascript is :

```
    function showUser(str){

        if(str == ""){

        }else{
            var myDiv = document.getElementById("sub");
            var arr = [];
             var status = false;
            $.ajax({ //sending to DB
               url: 'subEx.php',
               type: 'post',
               data: { field:str},

               success:function(response){                     
                   var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
                    for(var x in parsed){
                      arr.push(parsed[x]);
                    }
                  // console.log(arr[0]);
                    //Create and append select list
            var selectList = document.createElement("select");
            selectList.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");

            myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

            //Create and append the options


            for(var i = 0 ; i <= arr.length ; i ++){
            console.log(arr[0].NameSub);

            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", arr[i].NameSub);
            option.text = arr[i].NameSub;
            selectList.appendChild(option);




            }


        }
            });

            return true;
        }
    }
```

I connected the two combox with the DB but when i commited a submit i couldn't access to the value of the second combox.

How can i get the value and use it while i submit?

Comment: is the processing done by the `calc` function? Is it in that function that you are unable to process the content from the second dropdown?

Comment: Hi, calc() is an empty function the problem is when i commit a submit. I don't getting the value from the second <select>

Answer (score 1):

Your second `<select>` tag has no `name` attribute. So, nothing is sent on submit.

```
selectList.setAttribute("name", "name_of_select");
```

Then, you should have `$_POST['name_of_select']` available in server side.

Also, in your HTML, you should have `<form>` tag to be able to submit your values.
Finally, your `while` loop seems to be unclosed.

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <div style="margin:5px">סוג הפעילות
       <select name="ex" id="user" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
           <option value="0">  </option>
           <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row['NameEx'];?>"><?php echo $row['NameEx'];?></option>
           <?php } /*end while */ ?>
       </select>
    </div>

    <div name="sub" id="sub" style="margin:5px"> תת פעילות</div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit1" onclick="calc()" >חשב</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, i add the selectList.setAttribute("name", "name_of_select"); to my code and still nothing. any other suggestions?

Comment: @Tal. Hi. Sorry I haven't seen your comment update. Do you have a `<form>` tag?

Comment: @Tal I've updated the answer. Also, what your `calc()` function do?

Comment: Hi, I have a <form> tag, and the function calc() do nothing.

Comment: I am geting a post array but only for the tags i have inside the <form> tag. For the <select > that i am creating in the javascript i am not get the new value inside the post array

Comment: @Tal Your second select must be inside your form to get its value in PHP, and must have a name attribute.

Comment: There's no other way? The second combox displays value from php after its getting the information from the first combox.  How  can i enter to the <form> the second <select> in order to get and use the value from the first <select>?

Comment: @Tal If your form is around `<div id="sub">`  it should work, because your select is filled into this div. Look at the HTML of the answer.

Comment: Hi, my html is like what you wrote and i still didn't get any value in post from the second combox. when i use print_r($_POST) in my php  i am getting the 
 Array([weight] => 0 [ex] => שחיה [activ] => 0 [submit1] => ) the second combox value is not here.

Answer (score 0):

To help you resolve the problem I quickly put together a demo based around your code after modifying the javascript code a little. One thin I noticed was the use of `JSON.parse` which threw an error - presumably because jQuery is smart enough to automagically parse the response as JSON with or without the `dataType: 'json'` declaration.

The PHP code is simply to emulate whatever your `subEx.php` script actually does - and returns dummy data that is used by the ajax callback to build the second select menu.

The url has been commented out for the demo - as this sends the request to the same page.

The callback uses [`new Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) and the `add` method for [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) to simplify a little further. There was no need in the original to populate an array and then iterate through that array to build the options - just iterate through the source data once should be fine.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['field'] ) ){
        /* 
            This is simply to emulate whatever subEx.php actually does
            and return a suitable JSON response - it is dummy data
        */

        $tmp=array();
        $field=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'field', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

        if( $field ){
            /* 
                populate array with dummy data used
                to build seconds dropdown menu.
            */
            for( $i=0; $i < 20; $i++ ){
                $tmp[]=array( 'NameSub' => uniqid( 'NameSub-' ) );
            }
        }
        header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        exit( json_encode( $tmp ) );
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>jQuery - menus   </title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

        <script>
            function calc(){
                /* empty function */
            }
            function showUser( str ){
                if( str != '' ){
                    var oSelect, json, oDiv, obj;

                    oDiv = document.getElementById('sub');
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'', /* removed for demo - subEx.php */
                        type:'post',
                        data:{ field:str },
                        dataType:'json',
                        success:function( json ){
                            oSelect = document.createElement('select');
                            oSelect.name='mySelect';
                            oSelect.id='mySelect';
                            oDiv.appendChild( oSelect );

                            for( var n in json ){
                                obj=json[n];
                                oSelect.add( new Option( obj.NameSub, obj.NameSub ) );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <div style='margin:5px'>סוג הפעילות
                <select name='ex' id='user' onchange='showUser( this.value )'>
                     <option selected hidden>Please Select
                     <?php
                        for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
                            printf('<option value="%s">%s', uniqid( 'option-'.$i ), 'test '.$i );
                        }
                     ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div name='sub' id='sub' style='margin:5px'> תת פעילות</div>
            <div>
                <button class='btn btn-primary' type = 'submit' name='submit1' onclick='calc()' >חשב</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                /* 
                    Display POST data after form submission 
                    to see value of second dropdown.
                */
                printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

After submitting the form the output is going to be similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [ex] => option-35a92db54def19
    [mySelect] => NameSub-5a92db56dde29
    [submit1] => 
)
```

You can clearly see that the new select menu value is in the POST data.